# Angular: Hide parent component but show child

Tags: css, angular

in the following example, is there any way to show the child component on the page but hide the outer component? maybe with some kind of attribute/styling?

```
<abc-component>
    <def-component>
    </def-component>
</abc-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically, it is not possible, but there is an alternative way.

You can set the `position` style of the `def-component` to either `absolute` or `fixed`. To hide the `abc-component`, you should set the `width` and `height` to 0. (of course padding and margin as well).

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it, that's just a part of how parent and child component relationship works. The parent **contains** the child component, so if you hide it, you also hide whatever is inside it.

What you can do instead, is wrap both of them with `<ng-template>` then hide whatever is necessary like this:

```js
<ng-template>
    <abc-component *ngIf="false">
    </abc-component>
    <def-component>
    </def-component>
</ng-template>
```